# Why won't my html canvas game work on firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, html5-canvas

I made this simple game for valentine's day and for some reason my canvas isn't drawing to the screen on firefox. It works in safari and chrome with no issues whatsoever. I'm new to web dev so I'm all out of ideas here.

http://schwiz.net/valentine/?lover=StackOverflow%20User

Comment: It doesn't work well with Opera either: http://i.imgur.com/pfZLNmu.png

Comment: lol, at least it is showing something.. but yeah thanks.

Comment: This line looks phishy: `window.setInterval("gameLoop()", timeStep);` - try changing this to `window.setInterval(gameLoop, timeStep);`

Comment: Loop is executing for sure I've been stepping through it int he debugger. the context.fillImage and fillText just don't do anything on firefox.  I did make your change and it didn't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
function updateCanvasDimensions() {
  canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

instead of `document.width` and `document.height`. I that seems to work on both Firefox and Chrome, but I haven't tried it on other browsers.

**edit** see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.width

Comment: That fixed the canvas thanks!  Any idea why my set innerHTML code doesn't work on endGame in firefox now?  The div style.display stays none. Again, working fine in firefox and chrome, I'm pushing your fix to my server now.

Comment: I assume you fixed this by now? The version you have now seems to work fine on Firefox (18.0.2).

Comment: Yes thanks, resetting the audio time was causing the javascript to stop working even though it didn't log any errors. When I moved that call to the last line of the function it started working.